# Excel - Automate VBA without have to run everytime

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to automate my VBA without have to run the VBA every time someone change the cell. I try to use Worksheet_Change(ByRef Target As Range) but I got compiler error. Below is my code without using worksheet_change event. This is a shared excel workbook so I need it to be automated every time someone fill a new cell or make change.

```
 Option Explicit

 Public Sub getEmails()

 Dim names As Range, findRange As Range
 Dim splitNames
 Dim selectedEmails As String, i As Long, lRow As Long

 Set names = Sheets("Email").Range("B1:C23") ' names range from lookup table from    different worksheet


With Sheets("Sheet2")
' loop column K untill last row with data (staring from row 2 >> modify where you data starts)
For lRow = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ' fill array directly from cell
    splitNames = Split(.Range("B" & lRow), ",")

    For i = 0 To UBound(splitNames)
        ' find the range matching the name
        Set findRange = names.Find(What:=Trim(splitNames(i)), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

        ' if match found, get the email and store to selected emails variable
        If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
            If selectedEmails = "" Then ' first email of this row
                selectedEmails = findRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Else  ' add a ";" to separate email addresses
                selectedEmails = selectedEmails & "; " & findRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
            End If

        End If
    Next i

    .Range("C" & lRow) = selectedEmails
    ' clrear all variables and arrays for next cycle
    Erase splitNames
    selectedEmails = ""
Next lRow

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: What error are you seeing?

Comment: I think you are updating column C with the email addresses for the people's name in column B (where each cell in column B has multiple people, comma-delimited).  So you need to (1) update `Sheet2!C` for a single row when the value in `Sheet2!B` for that row has changed and (2) update `Sheet2!C:C` when any cell in `Email!B:C` changes.  Is that correct?  What was your `Worksheet_Change` event code that didn't work, and which worksheet was it in?

Comment: I got this error "Compile Error: Procedure declaration does not match description of event or procedure having same name" @dgorti

Comment: This code works fine, but I just want to automate it. I just change getEmails() to Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByRef Target As Range)

Comment: You need to place the `Worksheet_Change` sub into the `Sheet2` code module, did you?

Comment: I put this code at the Sheet 2 module code @A.S.H

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByRef Target As Range)` <-- ByRef: error

It should be:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)  '<-- ByVal
```

This should be the prototype of the sub and it should be placed in Sheet2 code module (as you already did).

**Addendum**

Here's a refactored version of your sub, should be faster and more maintainable. It triggers the operation only if something has changed in column B, and acts only on that part that has changed, updating the neighboring cell in column C.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim B As Range: Set B = Range("B2:B" & Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    Dim r As Range: Set r = Intersect(B, Target)
    If r Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

    Dim findRange As Range, selectedEmails As String, i

    On Error GoTo Finish
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Dim names As Range: Set names = Sheets("Email").Range("B1:C23")  ' names range from lookup table from    different worksheet
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In r
       Dim splitNames : splitNames = Split(cel.value, ",")
       For Each i In splitNames
           ' find the range matching the name
           Set findRange = names.Find(What:=Trim(i), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
               LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
               MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

            ' if match found, get the email and store to selected emails variable
            If Not findRange Is Nothing Then
                If selectedEmails = "" Then ' first email of this row
                    selectedEmails = findRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
                Else  ' add a ";" to separate email addresses
                    selectedEmails = selectedEmails & "; " & findRange.Offset(0, 1).Value
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        cel.Offset(, 1).Value = selectedEmails
        selectedEmails = ""
    Next cel

Finish:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Comment: I have already change to Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range) and got no error, but I cannot update a cell, it hanged the workbook

Comment: It worked but it made the sheet froze for a couple of minutes. Anyway thanks

Comment: @gpsrosak This is expected since you are making all the updates for a single change. Your sub has a lot of room for optimization and speedup. At least we made it work atm.

Comment: @gpsrosak please try the modified code, it should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your Worksheet_Change event is behind the sheet you are working with and not in a Module.  Right-click the sheet and select View Code.  Put your code into the window that opens.

Check this out.

http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/events.html